# Merge by column name R

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I've got

```
a <- matrix(c(1,3,4,2,2,6,3,1,6), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Apples", "Pears", "Oranges")))

  Pears Apples Oranges
1     1      3       4
2     2      2       6
3     3      1       6

b <- matrix(c(1,3,2,6,3,6), nrow = 3, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c( "Pears", "Oranges")))

  Pears Oranges
1     1       4
2     2       6
3     3       6
```

I want to merge them to get a result as such:

```
 Pears Apples Oranges
1     1      3       4
2     2      2       6
3     3      1       6
4     1     Na       4
5     2     Na       6
6     3     Na       6
```

Ie, **combine them by column name an leave Na/s where the second frame lacks values, for a general case of bigger matrix a, smaller matrix b**

rbind does not work, merge does something weird. What am I after? I could do with the most memory efficient thing available too, as this is eventually going to be done a large number of times, with a lot of column names.

Thanks,

-N

EDIT: I probably should have mentioned this when I asked originally, but I actually want to achieve the exact effect as above, but with some pretty major caveats:

I'm using matrices

The first matrix will always contain all and more colnames than the second

I possibly want to create a big.matrix from package bigmemory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a more generic approach, in case you have multiple column in `a` and `b` that need to be added:

```
b.toAdd <- setdiff (names(a), names(b))
if (length(b.toAdd))
  b[, b.toAdd] <- NA

a.toAdd <- setdiff (names(b), names(a))
if (length(a.toAdd))
  a[, a.toAdd] <- NA

rbind(a, b)
```

### Update:

Just noticed your comment about needing memory efficiency. 
In that case, you probably want to use `data.table` since using `<-` will create unnecessary copies.
`data.table` isntead has a `:=` operator which is significantly more efficient.

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(a)
b <- data.table(b)


if (length(b.toAdd <- setdiff (names(a), names(b))))
    b[, c(b.toAdd) := NA]

if (length(a.toAdd <- setdiff (names(b), names(a))))
    a[, c(a.toAdd) := NA]

rbind(a, b, use.names=TRUE)

#    Pears Apples Oranges
# 1:     1      3       4
# 2:     2      2       6
# 3:     3      1       6
# 4:     1     NA       4
# 5:     2     NA       6
# 6:     3     NA       6
```

---

**search SO for `[r] data.table benchmarks` to get an idea of the improvements**

Comment: Thanks, but as I edited to mention, I'm using matrices, and this doesn't work for them. I changed names() to colnames(), but I'm getting Error in b[, b.toAdd] <- NA : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @N.McA. the second part of this answer should still work.   (ie, using `a <- data.table(matrix_a)` etc...

Comment: right, but I'm eventually going to need to get this working with bigmemory... Or will data.tables allow me to have file-backed objects?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  However, the idea behind `:=` is to not have to copy an entire object just to add a column. Therefore, there will be less of a demand on your memory and possibly no need for costly file I/O.   Best way to know for sure is to experiment.

Comment: This method also seems to be adding Booleans into my data somehow? I'm  experimenting :P

Comment: Ah, yes.  NA is logical.   Use `:=as.integer(NA)`  (_or whichever is appropriate_) instead

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
rbind(a, cbind(b, Apples=NA))
  Pears Apples Oranges
1     1      3       4
2     2      2       6
3     3      1       6
4     1     NA       4
5     2     NA       6
6     3     NA       6
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're after, but you can merge with the added column (similar to jmsinger's answer):

```
merge(a, cbind(b, Apples=NA), all=TRUE)
##   Pears Apples Oranges
## 1     1      3       4
## 2     1     NA       4
## 3     2      2       6
## 4     2     NA       6
## 5     3      1       6
## 6     3     NA       6
```